# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter'

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have a .Net Core 3.0 windows desktop simple project that references following NuGet packages:

1. Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms(3.0.0-preview.3.19128.7)
2. Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App(3.0.0-preview.3.27504-2)
3. runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetAppHost(3.0.0-preview3-27503-5)

When I add new form to application, I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I use **visual studio 2019** , target **.net core 3.0**.

How to fix this error?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appear when I use the designer of form.

According this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms)

Visual Form Designer is not yet available for Windows Forms and WPF .NET CORE projects. 
But regarding to their roadmap, designer will be available as part of a Visual Studio 2019 update.

After the available this part, this error is also fix.

**Edit:**

according to this [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/).

To enable the designer, download and install the [Windows Forms .NET Core Designer VSIX package.](https://aka.ms/winforms-designer) and update `Visual Studio` to `16.3.1` version.

it's resolved for me.

I hope is useful.

Comment: [Using the Classic WinForms Designer in WinForms Core](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/1225f79dce17253a629d1a65c3c13f7a77cbaba1/Documentation/winforms-designer.md)

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/

Answer (score 0):

First, download and install WinFormsDesigner from https://github.com/dotnet/winforms

Then create WinForms app from a command line instead of doing it from within VS 
(i.e. Open cmd in your folder of choice and type: dotnet new winforms)

It's an early stage of development and WinForms Designer wasn't working without taking these steps for me either.